# Mooer GE100 with only headphones for beginners

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, beginner, effects-pedal, headphones

So, I've been wanting to get a multi-effects processor (Mooer GE100) with my first electric guitar purchase(been playing an acoustic since 2 years). I won't be buying an amp tho, only a headphone(AKG 240 mkII) to directly connect to the processor. I made the call to not buy an amp and spend on a multi effects processor bcz I have a tight budget, and figured I would get more sounds out of the processor than from an ordinary amp.

So, my setup will be:

A guitar: Harley Benton ST-62
A multi-fx processor: Mooer GE100
A pair of headphones: AKG 240 Mk.II

Is there any problems or concerns i should consider with this kind of setup ?

Comment: Can't say anything about that specific FX processor, but generally that should work fine. Just remember you might need a 6.3 to 3.25mm headphone adapter unless your  headphones have a big plug.

Comment: All should be well. Until you reach the point where you want to play with others. Then you'll realise how much difference playing through an amp. makes.

Comment: I mean, a lot of pros play through a multieffects pedal and a PA system these days and they seem to be fine.

Comment: I use earphones too. I got myself locked down in the Philippines. The apartment I had to rent has zero tolerance for noise, so headphones on your Mooer will be great for practice. Sure the sound will be much better through an Amp but earphones for practice give and then no annoyed neighbours.